# Is there any way to convert a list to dict? (with variable names staying the same)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So, I have a list of variables, let's call these `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.

```
a = 1
b = 45
c = 73
d = "foo"
e = "bar"
f = 90
g = "banana"
variables = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

Now, I want to make turn it into;

```
data = {
"a":1,
"b":45,
"c":73,
"d":"foo",
"e":"bar",
"f":90,
"g":"banana"
}
```

How can I do that? I also want the first parts (`"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, etc.) to stay the same as the variable names.

Comment: You don't have a list of variables. Lists don't contain variables, lists contain *objects*. The fact that those objects happened to be referenced by some variables is irrelevant, and not something the `list` has any knowledge. This sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to get the variable name of a variable as a string. Either do it by hand or when storing the values put them in a dictionary from the beginning.

Comment: @Einliterflasche I mean, there is no end to the wackiness one *can* do. But the better question is really, *should one do that*?

Comment: A fun python doc to read: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-can-my-code-discover-the-name-of-an-object

Comment: Hi, I'm using [https://data.cdc.gov/Case-Surveillance/United-States-COVID-19-Cases-and-Deaths-by-State-o/9mfq-cb36/data]this cdc api, which isn't in json format. When you use it, you get a list, where the first 8 (I think) objects are useless for the info I'm trying to get (state, tot_cases, conf_cases, prob_cases, new_case, pnew_case, tot_death, conf_death, prob_death, new_death, pnew_death, created_at, (1/2)

Comment: consent_cases, consent_deaths), so I created variables for those objects (like state = i[len(i)-14]), and added those objects to a list. Now, I want to convert said list to a dict object, where, for example state = i[len(i)-(1+13)] becomes 
`data = {
"state":i[len(i)-(1+13)]
}`

Comment: add important/relevant information by [edit]ing your question instead of using comments

Comment: See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to understand why getting the variable names is impossible.

Comment: @kramboll, this is not possible. You may raise another question regarding text processing, I believe there are solutions to your issues but not this.

Comment: @krambol, I check with the cdc and downloaded the data, I created a list something like this. `[{'state': 'FL', 'tot_cases': '1569134', 'conf_cases': None, ...}, {'state': 'UT', 'tot_cases': '359641', 'conf_cases': '359641.0', ...}, ...]` Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`locals()` returns a `dict` with all your local variables. You just need to filter this down to the variables you want.

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = 1, 45, 73, 'foo', 'bar', 90, 'banana'
variables = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
data = {n: v for n, v in locals().items() if n in variables}
```

Comment: This is `O(LV)` time complexity where `L` and `V` are the sizes of `locals()` and `variables` respectively. It can be reduced to `O(V)` if you do `data = {n: ls[n] for ls in (locals(),) for n in variables}`. (You can't do `{n: locals()[n] for n in variables}` because then `locals()` refers to the local scope of the dictionary comprehension.)

Comment: @Oli Only if measurements show this is somehow a performance hot spot in your app should you resort to inscrutable solutions.  Otherwise, readability and maintainability should prevail.  I've wasted too much of my life already trying to read someone else's code when that someone tried to save a few nanoseconds.

Comment: I agree that premature optimisation is generally not good and that this is likely not going to be very much faster, but I think in this case my alternative is also very close in readability, especially if the `locals()` was factored out into a separate variable. Also, it's good to be in the habit of writing lower time complexity solutions by default, especially when it is no harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the names of objects from their values like this, however it is not perfect. The `locals()` dictionary (a python builtin) is a dictionary from all variable names in the current scope (usually either global scope or inside a function). You can use this dictionary to get a mapping from objects in the current scope to their names, for example, you might try `reverse_locals = {id(v):n for n,v in locals().items()}`, however not all types are hashable, so this may raise an error. Also dictionary lookup checks for equality, and it would be better to check for identity. Both of these problems can be solved at once by using the builtin `id` function, which returns a unique number for each object.

```
a = 1
b = 45
c = 73
d = "foo"
e = "bar"
f = 90
g = "banana"
variables = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]

reverse_locals = {id(v):n for n,v in locals().items()}
data = {reverse_locals[id(v)]: v for v in variables}
```

This approach works fairly well, however it would need some modification to work when some variables are locals and others global, and would not work at all when some of the variables are out of scope - for example the following will not work:

```
a = 1
b = "foo"

variables = [a]
variables.append(b)

def add_c():
    c = "bar"
    variables.append(c)

add_c()

reverse_locals = {id(v):n for n,v in locals().items()}
data = {reverse_locals[id(v)]: v for v in variables} # <-- KeyError
```

Also note that if two variables point to the same object, there is no way to tell them apart:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a

variables = [a, b]

reverse_locals = {id(v):n for n,v in locals().items()}
data = {reverse_locals[id(v)]: v for v in variables}
# data == {'b': [1, 2, 3]}
# no way to recover both 'a' and 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're putting in `variables` with:
`variables = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]` are the *values* of variables `a`, `b`, etc, not the variable's name. So in order to do what you want, a way of determining the associated variable names is needed.

Fortunately Python has a couple of built-in functions, [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), that can help doing that. They each return a dictionary, mapping either the current local or global variables, to their respective values. The obvious problem is that what's needed is a way to do the exact reverse—i.e. look up a variable name given its value. In addition there's also the potential issue is that a local and global variable can have the same name and the same value could be assigned to more than one variable.

The mapping problem can be solved by creating reverse dictionaries that map values to corresponding variable names. The uniqueness issue with the values can be solved by using the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) of the dictionary values, which is an integer value guaranteed to be unique and stay the same for the object during its lifetime, instead of the value itself.

Below is an example showing how to do these things. Note that in order to avoid having to look each list value up in two dictionaries, one for the local variables and a another for the globals, the two are logically grouped together by making use of the `collections` module's [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) class which allows them to be treated like a single entity.

```
from collections import ChainMap

# Define some gobal variables.
b = 42
g = "banana"


def rev_dict(dict_):
    """ Return dict mapping id of values to corresponding keys of given dict. """
    return {id(value): key for key, value in dict_.items()}


def get_data():
    # Define some local variables.
    a = 1
    b = 45  # Note same name as a global variable.
    c = 73
    d = "foo"
    e = "bar"
    f = 90

    values = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]  # Note mixture of local and global variables.
    namespace = ChainMap(rev_dict(locals()), rev_dict(globals()))
    return {namespace[id(value)]: value for value in values}


data = get_data()
print(data)  # -> {'a': 1, 'b': 45, 'c': 73, 'd': 'foo', 'e': 'bar', 'f': 90, 'g': 'banana'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever approach you take, you're going it have to specify a list of variable names at some point.  Given this, you might as well just write out the dictionary:

```
data = { "a":a, "b":b, "c":c, "d":d, "e":e, "f":f, "g":g }
```